# Cordova/Phonegap change format input type date html5

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, date, input

I'm writing an Cordova/Phonegap app and I want to change the format of

```
<input type="date"/>
```

because it change with system's browser. I want to set up it in this format "dd-mm-yyyy". How can I change this format? If I can't change it, is there alternative solution? With alternative solution, if there is, I want to use the calendar of the devide like when I use the tag above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: yes but this question return 3 years ago...